`DispatchSource.makeReadSource` vs `DispatchIO.read`
There seems to be a fair amount of overlap here where both are dispatch objects that manage operations on a file descriptor.
Any idea why we have both APIs, and why one would be preferred over the other?

DispatchIO is a slightly higher-level abstraction, and is great for random-access reading and/or you want it to do the buffering for you. DispatchSourceRead is a slightly lower-level abstraction.
